# Dedicated Recovery Partition For Every Windows Feature Update

Tags: windows-10

I noticed that if i do feature update on windows 10, windows created dedicated recovery partition afterwards.

Is there way so windows use existing dedicated recovery partition for every windows feature update ?

Thank you.

Comment: I have never seen this happen, post a screenshot of disk management please.

Answer (score 0):

Windows will create a recovery partition for really major upgrades, like Windows 7
to Windows 10, but most often the reason is that the size of the recovery image has
exceeded the size of the partition.

You might in such a case see several recovery partitions, each new one larger than
the others.

Apart from this case, Windows will not allocate new recovery partitions.
If you have many of them, you may delete the older ones, although I wouldn't
bother as they are relatively small when compared to the sizes of modern hard disks.

If this keeps on happening, then Windows is in a bad shape and should be repaired.